# Android: Show AlertDialog inside Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show an AlertDialog inside an AsyncTask inside a Fragment, but just so that the AlertDialog is inside that Fragment, and not "blocking" the whole application, so that I can go through my tabs and on one fragment there is a AlertDialog blocking that Fragment.

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait...", "Fetching data", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

ProgressDialogs are generally frowned upon by the Android Design Guidelines and in your case they are definitely problematic due to their modal nature. It would be preferable to include a ProgressBar component in each of your fragments and show / hide (from your async task).

http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android-progress-bar-indeterminate/

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that I may use this if there isn't another solution!